# How to get previous state in redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

i want to set state to his previous value
on click on button........... to change redux-state to previous redux-state

reducer file

```
export var key = (state = 0, action) => {
    if (action.type === 'changeKey') {
        return action.playload
    }
    else {
        return state
    }
}
```

action file

```
export var keyAction = (name) => {
    return {
        type: 'changeKey',
        playload: name,
    }
}
```

3 file

```
<Text onPress={()=>{
//what i need to write here ???
}}> Set redux-state to previous value of redux-state</Text>
```

Comment: I mean you could cache the current state with a variable or even in the reducer itself. `state = { current: 0, prev: 0 }` and then have an action to update the states current value to the last value. But why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make array list- every time i add key  it will add the value on previous array

When i want to set redux-state to previous state i just delete last item of an array, and set redux-state to last item of that array

```
var list = [0]

export var keyAction = (name) => {
    list = [...list, name]
    return {
        type: 'changeKey',
        playload: name,
    }
}
export var keyBackAction = () => {
    list.splice(-1)
    return {
        type: 'getBack',
        playload: list[list.length - 1],
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: bro... everybody can uderstand this,  ( i edited now )

Answer (score 2):

You can use `redux-undo` (https://github.com/omnidan/redux-undo) or implement your own custom logic following this documentation https://redux.js.org/usage/implementing-undo-history

Answer (score -1):

You should dispatch your redux action

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'


const FC = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    return (
        <Text onPress={() => dispatch(keyAction("stackoverflow"))}>
            Set redux-state to previous value of redux-state
        </Text>
    )
}
```

You also wrote *playload* instead of **payload**

You can get the previous state before Dispatch a type in the action

```
export const keyAction = (name) => (dispatch, getState) => {
    const previousValue = getState().REDUCER_NAME

    console.log(previousValue);

    return dispatch({
        type: 'changeKey',
        playload: name
    })
}
```

Comment: Hi - dispatch(keyAction("stackoverflow")) - will get me a value of redux-state - but i want previous value of redux-state

Comment: You can use getState() method in action to get the previous value, I updated my answer